Not getting all the possible options when chatting over my chatbot
I am trying to build a simple chatbot over a PDF document using Llamaindex
so its like , some experiences/trips catalogue
and if i ask lets say , give me all experiences related to "Fashion"
i just get normally 2 experiences, though there are more than 7 "fashion" related experiences
any idea what i am missing and how can i see each and every exprience which is Fashion related for example
here is the code screenshot


Did u get anywhere with this? I am having a similar problem. I am using open ai embedding and open ai for querying.

Usually this happens due to problem with your Embedding model or chunking strategy. Try changing the Embedding model to something better such as OpenAIEmbedding or anything else. Also, change the llm model to higher version 3.5 sonnet. Then try.
